# Identical bootstrap column code functions differently

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I started learning HTML this week and hoped to make my own website using bootstrap. I have run across a most curious error however, as simple code that should create a row with two pieces of text on the same line is not working for one snippet of code and is working for another even though the two are **exactly identical.**

Below is the code that I'm running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<!-- Below: My original code that wasn't working, boiled down to be as simple as possible -->
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-4">
      I'm foo
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      I'm bar
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Below: Code I appropriated from https://blog.theodo.com/2018/03/stop-using-bootstrap-layout-thanks-to-css-grid/ -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      I'm foo
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      I'm bar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I ran this code on both my local machine and an online HTML compiler and got the following result: 
[image: output of code above in mozilla firefox, google chrome, and an online HTML compiler (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_html_compiler)]

So why is the same code outputting a different result? Why is the text in the top row indented while the other isn't? I tried switching the order of the two rows and it still didn't matter. I'm really stumped. I'd appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: You have fancy quotes surrounding the first row class: `<div class=“row”>`

Comment: You are correct. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line nine you have written “ instead of ". Looks almost the same, but makes all the difference!

Comment: Holy cow. Did not know that mattered, and am incredibly impressed that you spotted that. You are an absolute wizard and I will mark your answer as correct as soon as I can. Thank you!